# Is there a way to view rptdesign as PDF without creating PDF file first?

Tags: java, pdf, birt

Currently I'm viewing *birt rptdesign* as PDF by creating to PDF file first as follow :

```
design = engine.openReportDesign("c:/temp/customer.rptdesign");
task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
PDFRenderOption options = new PDFRenderOption();
options.setOutputFileName("c:/temp/customer.PDF");
options.setOutputFormat("PDF");
```

Then I open it with *desktop* as follow:

```
File file = new File("c:/temp/customer.PDF");
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Is there a way to view it as PDF directly without creating PDF file first?

I'm using jdk-8u181-windows-i586 and birt-runtime-4.8.0-20180626.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sample servlet, or write your own servlet.

Comment: Is it by replacing setOutputFileName with setOutputStream method?

Comment: Yes, that is basically the way the sample servlet is working. You can download the source code of the sample servlet from the BIRT web site somewhere.